# How to separate 2 label far apart with tkinter Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to separate 2 elements far apart in Tkinter.

I have tried using column such that label_1 is column = 0, row = 0 and label 2 is column 19 and label 3 is column 20 but this still results in them being side by side in the middle. I have set my frame with pack(side =TOP).

I also tried using pack on my label such that label 2 & 3 are right and label 1 is left but still ended up with an unexpected result.

Hence is there a way to separate the 2 elements far apart?

**Example**

[image: enter image descriptionfhere]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I use a frame using pack() to display.

`self.frameTop.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=NO)`

Apparently the condition expand and fill played an important role in display the expected result.

The bottom shows the code for the layout of each element and its anchoring

```
        # Monty Logo
        self.icon = Label(self.frameTop, image = self.iconImage, font=('Zilla Slab', 16, 'bold'), borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, bg="#FFFFFF")
        self.icon.pack(padx = 8, pady = 8, side = LEFT, anchor=NW)

        # Use a canvas line to deine the cutting
        self.labelSeperator = Separator(self.window, orient="horizontal")#Label(self.frameTop, bg="#000000", height= 2, width = int(ws)).pack(side= BOTTOM)

        self.labelTitle_time = Label(self.frameTop, font=('Zilla Slab', 16), anchor = "w", borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, bg="#FFFFFF")
        self.labelTitle_time.pack(padx=8,side = RIGHT, anchor=CENTER)

        self.labelTitle_day = Label(self.frameTop, font=('Zilla Slab', 16, 'bold'), borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0,bg="#FFFFFF")
        self.labelTitle_day.pack(side = RIGHT, anchor=CENTER)
```